# Break from while which is inside forEach

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, while-loop

Hello I have to break from the while loop. In that while loop I am calling an asynchronous function. I have to check if a certain field from the output of that async call is empty then I have to break from while else I will call again to that async function. I have tried this :

```
var options = {
      headers : {
         'Fk-Affiliate-Id':'xxxxxxx' ,
         'Fk-Affiliate-Token' : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      }
   };
var state = ['approved','tentative','cancelled','disapproved'];
state.forEach(element => {
  options.url = 'https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/report/orders/detail/json?startDate='+startDate+'&endDate='+endDate+'&status='+element+'&offset=0';
    loop : while(true){
        // This is the async call
        request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
          var data = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(data);
          // I have to check whether next is empty or not ?
          if(data.next === ''){
            // I will perform some action on data here
            break loop;
          }
          else{
            // I will perform some action on data here
            options.url = data.next;
          }
        });
      }
});
```

But this showing error Unsyntactic break. How to break from while loop?

Comment: Your `break` statement is inside an async callback.  You can't break out of the while loop from within another function and certain not from an async function.  Even if it would let you run that code, it would never work because the async callback can't get called until the `while()` loop is done.  JS is single threaded.  The `while()` loop has to finish before your ajax callback can ever get called.  This is just completely misguided code.  Please restate what you are trying to accomplish and folks can help with a proper way to achieve that.

Comment: I will get  data from async call in the body variable. I will check if there is next field is empty or not. If next is non empty I have to make request to that url which is in the next. Otherwise I just break and retreive another element from  from state variable and repeat process

Comment: 'The way this site works, you need to use the "edit" link to add the info about what you are trying to accomplish to your question, not just in the comments.

Comment: now I have edited what I want to achieve

Comment: It's not clear how many times you want to make a request. Is it once per state or per state you make requests until next is an empty string.

Comment: Its definetely once per state. And for every state if next is present I will make another request for that state until next is non empty for that state

Comment: What end results are you trying to achieve?  In your description, you just make a bunch of ajax calls, but don't actually collect any result.

Comment: I have edited post where I will perform some action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't need while loop there. You just want to stop when you reach desired result for one of the states.
It means you need to wait until async call completes, and only after that proceed with another state. One of the solutions is to make calls synchronous (if possible). 
Another solution is to create separate function for each state processing, and call it from async call callback:

```
var state = ['approved','tentative','cancelled','disapproved'];
// starting with first state
processState(0);

function processState(stateIdx){
    if(stateIdx >= state.length){
        // we tried all states and no success.
        return;
    }
    // some code
    request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
        // some code
        if(data.next !== ''){
            // we have more records for this state - call it one more time.   
            processState(stateIdx);
        } else {
            // done with this state, try next one.   
            processState(stateIdx + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: actually in the body I am getting some records from flipkart. If there are more then 500 records then it will send a url of more records in 'next'. Because I have to get all records so I am checking whether there is next or not. If next is present it means more records and I have to make another request for those records whose link is in the next. If no link in next means i have to check for next 'state'

Comment: @DevendraVerma: ok, it means we need to call that function for the same state if we have more records, otherwise - proceed with next state. I updated the answer. Btw, each state is independent and can be processed simultaneously?